# getting infrequent location update without notification?

Tags: android, geolocation

I want to get location update few times an hour from android device.

I think the following paragraph implies I can achieve what I want..

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits#tuning-behavior

> Consider whether your app's use cases for running in the background
>   cannot succeed at all if your app receives infrequent location
>   updates. If this is the case, you can retrieve location updates more
>   frequently by performing one of the following actions:
>
> Bring your app to the foreground

I understand it as `app can receive infrequent location updates without bring your app to the foreground`  (is my english bad ? :()

Google Map does track where you go without notifying you that "it is tracking you" when the map app is in the background , even when it's killed.

How can I achieve that ?

I've looked at

https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation.
https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation

and there seems to no way to *not* display the notification.

How can I achieve what google Map does?
tracking device location without showing the notification?

Is google having an unfair advantage at this?

Comment: Exactly what notification are you talking about? "Google Map does track where you go... even when it's killed" <-- Could you provide some evidence to back up that assertion?

Comment: google map shows list of places to review (even places that I visited while the app is terminated)

Comment: "app can receive infrequent location updates without bring your app to the foreground" <-- you have interpreted this correctly. I know of no way to do this without showing the "location" icon in the status bar. Otherwise, I don't know which notification you are talking about.